Modeling channel for Multiple users using Rayleigh
I am trying to reproduce the results of a given paper using their approach and model.
I have a difficult time understanding a statement in the paper and have doubts about how to interpret it.
The statement is about the modeling of the channel between each user and the base station, Quote:

The system model considered here represents an uplink NOMA-based network scenario (depicted in Fig. \ref{Fig:NOMA}) comprising BS and $N$ end-users, denoted by $U_{k}$, with $k\in\mathcal{A} = \{1,2,\ldots,N\}$. It is assumed that all nodes are deployed with a single antenna. The channel between the user of interest and BS is given by $\tilde{h}_k$ and assumed to be independent and identically distributed random variables (RVs) following Rayleigh fading.


Due to the considered uplink mode of communication, all end-users simultaneously transmit their individual messages to BS while ensuring the NOMA principle to be true through the path loss associated with their corresponding distances\footnote{Note that the similar assumption can be made using the principle of messages' priorities.}. Hence, the received signal at BS can be written as
\begin{align}
    \label{y}
    y = \sum_{k=1}^{N} s_{k} h_{k} + n,
\end{align}
where $s_{k}$ is the transmitted message of user $k$, with the transmit power defined as $\mathbb{E}\{s_{k} s_{k}^{*}\} = P_k$. For the sake of simplicity, we assume that all end-users transmit with the same power levels, {\it i.e.}, $P = P_1 = P_2 = \ldots = P_N$. $h_{k}$ is modelled as $h_{k} = \tilde{h}_k / \sqrt{d_k^{\tau}}$, where $d_k$ and $\tau$ indicate the corresponding distance and path-loss exponent. $n$ is an additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN) term, with zero mean and variance $\sigma_n^2$.

The simulation requires one to calculate the received signal y depending on the equation above. my question is what does the author eaxactly mean by "The channel between the user of interest and BS is given by $\tilde{h}_k$ and assumed to be independent and identically distributed random variables (RVs) following Rayleigh fading."?
is it simply that each user is assigned a random variable following Rayleigh and then the channel gain is calculated by using this RV and user distance-pathloss exponent? can this simplification can still be called Rayleigh fading channel? I don't really have experience with the topic but checking online comes with a more complicated (not similar) approach like Jake's model.
My second question is in case of NOMA, can the transmit power of each user be included in the channel rather than the symbol simulation wise? what I mean by that since we are only interested in the received signal y and since $h_{k}$ and $s_{k}$ are multiplicated together can i say that $h_{k}$(with power)= sqrt(P)$h_{k}$ & $s_{k}$=symbol only >> y=$s_{k}$$h_{k}$ is the same as $s_{k}$= sqrt(p)symbol >> y=$s_{k}$$h_{k}$?
here's my python code regarding this
# Define the path-loss exponent
tau = 2

# Define the distances of end-users from the base station
distances = np.array([50, 75, 100])

# Construct the channel coefficients (h_k) based on the given model
h_tilde = np.random.randn(num_transmitter) + 1j * np.random.randn(num_transmitter)
h = h_tilde / np.sqrt(distances ** tau)

# Construct F as a (num_receiver, num_transmitter) shaped numpy array
F = np.sqrt(transmit_power_linear) * h.reshape(1, -1)

Thanks in advance
